# How to listen changes of array in computed which comes from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an array of computed which is assembled from store's state:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    '$tg',
  ]),
  ...mapState({
    podcastList: state => state.listening.podcastList,
  }),
  tabList: {
    get() {
      const questionTitle = this.$tg('questions');
      const list = this.podcastList.map((poadcast, index) => ({
        ...poadcast,
        title: `${questionTitle}${index + 1}`,
        answers: [...poadcast.answers],
      }));
      return list;
    },
    set(value) {
      // I want dispatch action here..
      console.log('set', value);
    },
  },
}
```

the construction of `podcastList` is an object array:

```
[ 
  { 
    id: 1,  
    answers: [ 
      { id: 1, content:'foo'}, { id: 2, content: 'bar'}
    ]
  }, //.....
]
```

I'm using `v-for` to make a group of `input` which is bound of `answers`.
It looks like:

```
<div class="columns is-vcentered" v-for="(answer, index) in tab.answers" :key="index">
 <input type="text" v-model="answer.content"/>
</div>
// tab is an element of my tabList
```

My question: If I changed the value of input, the computed setter will not be triggered. I will get the message

> "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

I know that I cannot modify the state directly, but I don't know how to dispatch the action as the example of [official website](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html?fbclid=IwAR3OGBkS6wLegfyCQWE4kxLDOc--L-y1rz7upYc8O04JvdyBuvYJjNM4wQM#two-way-computed-property). Anybody could help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to change when calling the `set`? Can you show the code that triggered that error, it will help us get a better idea of what you were trying to do

Comment: I want to update the state of 'podcastList'.   The error pops up when I change the input's value (in vuex.esm.js )

Comment: I want to keep the flexibility of v-model and follow the pattern of vuex too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` would only work if you mapped `tabList` into it (something like `v-model="tabList"` in a component.

You'll have to change each answer directly, by using `value` and `@input` instead of `v-model`:

```
<div class="columns is-vcentered" v-for="(answer, index) in tab.answers" :key="index">
 <input type="text" :value="answer.content"
       @input="$store.commit('updateAnswer', { podcastId: tab.id, answerId: answer.id, newContent: $event.target.value })" />
</div>
// tab is an element of my tabList
```

And the `updateAnswer` mutation like:

```
mutations: {
  updateAnswer (state, { podcastId, answerId, newContent }) {
    state.listening.podcastList
        .find(podcast => podcast.id === podcastId)
        .map(podcast => podcast.answers)
        .find(answer => answer.id === answerId).content = newContent;
  }
}
```

--

You can perhaps reduce the boilerplate by creating a method:

```
methods: {
  updateAnswer(tab, answer, event) {
    this.$store.commit('updateAnswer', { podcastId: tab.id, answerId: answer.id, newContent: event.target.value });
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
<input type="text" :value="answer.content" @input="updateAnswer(tab, answer, $event)" />
```

Or by creating a component (which could be functional):

```
Vue.component('answer', {
  template: `
    <input type="text" :value="answer.content"
           @input="$store.commit('updateAnswer', { podcastId: tab.id, answerId: answer.id, newContent: $event.target.value })" />
  `
  props: ['tab', 'answer']
})
```

And use it like:

```
<div class="columns is-vcentered" v-for="(answer, index) in tab.answers" :key="index">
 <answer :tab="tab" :answer="answer"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this the only way to update the state by input event?  Because I have lot's of input to bind those events..  :(   anyway , thank you for  help~

Comment: I have added some alternatives, see if you think any is better. I'm afraid you really can't use the `computed`'s `set` function. That would only work if you had `v-model="tabList"`. Technically, you could add a `watcher` to your computed property and use it kinda like your setter, but that would be complicated as you would have to (1) clone each answer (in `answers: [...poadcast.answers]`) and, more importantly, (2) you would have to find out exactly which answer was edited every time the watcher is triggered.